# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/table.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 223

Tags: php, html

the error message for Line 223 is  everything was working fine  last month then godaddy had a update and now its giving this error

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=series&tag_ID=' . $series[$i]->term_id . '&post_type=anime' ?>">Edit</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                -->
            </td><td><?php echo $series[$i]['description']; ?></td><td><?php echo implode(", ", unserialize($series[$i]['genres'])); //$series[$i]['genres'];
         ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $g++;
    } else {
        //  $upperlimit++;

    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.  Tag removed.

Comment: The `$series` variable is a array or a object? What is the line 223?

Comment: i think its a array not sure and line 223 is the </table> but i think the problem is the echo implode location i just cant fix it still learning

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
$series[$i]['genres']
```

with

```
$series[$i]->genres
```

Comment: var_dump($series[$i]); what is the output of this?

Comment: $series[$i]; is it a object type array?

Comment: var_dump($series[$i]); what is the output of this?

Comment: just place the code 
 
var_dump($series[$i]);

Before anchor tag <a> link and check the output

Comment: it doesnt work the search feature seems to be broken when i change that thank you for trying to help

Comment: it seems that the decrypted version is not readable by the plugin so maybe thats why i didnt work the first time so ill try to encrtypt it and see if that works